# Jdbc check for capability - savepoint release

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, savepoints

I have generic jdbc code that works with all kinds of databases.
I have some apis that work with transactions and savepoints.

The problem is that some databases require you to release the savepoint manually

```
 conn.releaseSavepoint(savepoint1)
```

and some just throw an exeption when you do a manual release (most notably Oracle).

How can I check at run-time if the db has automatic savepoint release or if I need to do it
manually. And pls, I have some nice apis. I don't want to catch the exception, it's ugly
and error-prone in this case. The exception thrown is **java.sql.SqlException**, not something like "FeatureUnsupportedException". So if there is a real error and I foolishly catch it then I could fail at the whole transaction thing altogether.

Thanks

Comment: You've already said you don't want to hear this, but I think catching the exception is your best option

Comment: Javadoc says that it throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException if not supported. Now, if the implementations comply with the API, that's another story.

Comment: @Luciano You're right! Oracle decided to wrap all of their db exceptions in SqlException. But if I catch it, check the "cause" field. If it's SQLFeatureNotSupportedException work it, else throw it back !!! Thank you, you gave me the best idea so far.

Comment: @Luciano Sadly, even cause is wrapped in an SQLException. For now, I will skip manual releasing altogether. But I don't like it ...

Answer (score 7):

[In Oracle's 10g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#i1006293), I could spot the fact that this particular JDBC / ojdbc method is not supported:

> Note:
>   As of Oracle Database 10g, releaseSavepoint and oracleReleaseSavepoint are not supported. If you call either of the methods, then SQLException is thrown with the message "Unsupported feature".

In 11g, [the documentation seems to claim](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28094) otherwise:

> You remove a savepoint using the Connection.releaseSavepoint(Savepoint svpt) method.

But I can easily reproduce your issue also in 11g.

Comment: I've just tested on Oracle 19, SQLFeatureNotSupportedException is thrown when releaseSavepoint is called after Connection.rollback(Savepoint) because the rollback releases the savepoint, which is expected according to Oracle documentation: "When a transaction is committed or rolled back, all savepoints created in that transaction are automatically released and become invalid". However, after reading the Java documentation, I don't expect this exception because the feature is supported, I expect an SQLException: "the given Savepoint object is not a valid savepoint in the current transaction".

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass a DB vendor parameter into your class then you can simply map this behaviour for each vendor.