# Starting a new transaction from transactional method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Currently I have a controller which calls `@Transactional` annotated method in a service A which inserts the entity to a database, and then calls another method in a service B which updates the entity.

I would like to call only the method in a service A, which will then in turn call a method in a service B. First transaction should happen in a method of a service A, and another transaction should happen in a method of a service B.

I have tried to understand `@Transactional` annotation, its `isolation` and `propagation` in order to achieve this, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separate transaction in service B from transaction in service A then you have to start new transaction by using `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.

Mark your service B method with:

```
@Transaction(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Comment: Spring uses JDBC `Savepoint` under the hood, not all TX supports savepoints, and you need at least JDBC v3.0 and even Oravle 11 doesn't support it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667292/jdbc-check-for-capability-savepoint-release